# Can a Death Knight have Dual Talent specialization?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I didn't see an option to have 2 talent trees at my class trainer. Is this feature available for Death Knights?

Comment: Did you pay 1k gold at a Death Knight skill trainer? If you did you should have an achievement for it. If you have the achievement, but the tabs aren't showing up, you should put in a ingame ticket with a GM.

Comment: @Krazer It hasn't been 1k gold for quite a while. Just 30g now :)

Comment: @dpatchery ... I want my 970g back...

Comment: @Krazer It is not longer 1k gold to learn Dual Talent Specialization. (Side Note: Oh how much I wish I could have my gold back for all of the Dual Talent and Spell Ranks I purchased for all of my characters...)

Comment: Bah! I haven't played for so long. D:

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, all classes can learn dual talent specialization at level 30. However it first must be purchased from your trainer for 30g.

Simply return to Acherus, the Ebon Hold and talk to any of the trainers that would normally teach you new abilities. One of the speech options with the trainer should be "Learn About Dual Talent Specialization". Once you have done this, there should now be an extra tab on the right hand side of your talent trees to switch between the two talent specs.

You may need to have completed the Death Knight quest line to unlock this option. E.g. be level 58.

[image: Dual Talent Option]

Image source: Joystiq.com

Comment: I don't know how, but I didn't know notice I have two tabs in the talent tree. Thanks!

Comment: Just got dual spec and it was only 10g

Answer (score 6):

It is available for all classes, so yes your Death Knight can also have it